# Create a 500m x 500m grid over the shapefile in lat lon coordinates in r

Tags: r, plot, grid, latitude-longitude, shapefile

I can import and plot the shape file fine.  But the graticule is automatic and I need to plot is with 0.005 degrees to approximate a 0.5km x 0.5km grid.

---

```
library(sf)

my_shape <- read_sf(dsn=".",layer="19801010_ElAsnam_SURE2.0_ruptures")

plot(my_shape$geometry, xlab="Lat", ylab="Lon", cex.axis = .5, main="El Asnam",
     axes=TRUE, graticule=TRUE, col=my_shape$Comp_rank)
```

---

[image]

It looks like the next step is to use tmap for the tm_shape function but having trouble plotting my_shape file with that function.  It is unclear if I need to reformat the shapefile to conform to tmap input or if I'm just clueless with the tm_shape function.  The shapefile contains a linestring geometry of lat lon as well as Shape_Leng that specifies the line length at each coordinate point.